# Tangent vector of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

Let $\vec{\sigma}:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular and closed curve of class $C^1$, parametrized respect to the arc lenght. Is true that the map $\vec{\sigma}':[a,b]\longrightarrow S^1$ is surjective?

Comment: The initial question was: How can i prove that the map...

Comment: What is $S^1$ in this question ?

Comment: The notation is standard. With $S^1$ I denote the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is not true](http://sketchtoy.com/67288709).

Note that in the above drawing your map never reaches $(1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks! I have plotted the curve is $\vec{\alpha}(t)=(\sin(2t),\sin(t))$ and his tangent vector. Your attempt is true!